# Lync for IT support - problems with UAC prompts

Tags: uac, lync

I want to do IT-Support with Microsoft Lync Desktop sharing. Only problem, I have to disable UAC, because if UAC is enabled I get a black screen and the user has to click to accept, what I want to do.

Usually the user moves away from the computer while I'm working on it.

I know this is by design of Lync, but is there a better Solution then disabling UAC anyone aware of?

Comment: If you already know the solution what exactly is the question?  You can either have the user accept sharing their desktop ( even the biggest organizations do exactly this ) or disable UAC and reduce your overall security.

Comment: Hoped there must be something better.
It works with non-Microsoft tools instead of Lync, even in Microsoft Remote Desktop sessions I can click these UAC-dialogs.  Isn't there a policy setting which continues showing UAC-dialogs, but making them clickable from remote?

Comment: There might be have you looked?  Knowing
what verson of Lync is helpful.  Why don't you just use Microsfot Remote Desktop instead?  If you are trying to do remote technical support that is a better option.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed that information. It's Lync 2010, hosted on Microsoft servers (Office365). Remote Desktop needs pre-configured firewall rules, and therefore is not useable in all cases. I need to support many people moving around with their laptops, ...

Comment: I would contact Microsoft for assistance int his matter.